# Parse from a JS generated site

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to parse `(623) 337-****` from a JS generated site. My code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.spokeo.com/search?q=Joe+Henderson,+Phoenix,+AZ&sao7=t104#:18643819031')
content = browser.page_source
browser.quit()
m_obj = re.search(r"(\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\*{4})", content)
if m_obj:    
    print m_obj.group(0)
```

For some reason it doesn`t print anything. Any help is apreciated

Sidenote : Is there a faster way to do it in python

Comment: Check for sure what's inside `content`. The regex should be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that some of the content is loaded dynamically via post page load ajax requests.

You should wait until an element becomes visible ([documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html)) - then get the source code of the page:

```
import re

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.spokeo.com/search?q=Joe+Henderson,+Phoenix,+AZ&sao7=t104#:18643819031')

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "profile_details_section_header")))
content = browser.page_source

m_obj = re.search(r"(\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\*{4})", content)
if m_obj:    
    print m_obj.group(0)

browser.quit()
```

Or you can call `time.sleep()` or `browser.implicitly_wait()` instead - though it doesn't sound quite right.

Prints `(623) 337-****`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 for waiting option instead of naive (albeit it functional) sleep :)

Comment: @JonClements thanks, just realized that naive doesn't looks clean and nice.